# Problems with serializing a custom type in ASP.NET ViewState

Tags: asp.net, serialization, viewstate

I've got a little struct that I want to serialize in my ViewState. It looks something like this:

```
[Serializable]
private struct DayMoney
{
    public readonly DateTime ValidFrom;
    public readonly string CurrencyCode;
    public readonly double Amount;
}
```

It serializes just fine, but when I perform a postback/callback, I get an exception for deserializing it. Wrapped in a long list of InnerException's the root cause seems to be:

> Unable to find assembly 'BussinessTripModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Which is kinda ridiculous, because that assembly is definately loaded in the current AppDomain.

WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problems is very difficult to diagnose.

My suggestion is to use the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx) to diagnose why your particular assembly is not found. Keep in mind that some specific options of Fuslogvw that are not so easy to setup, luckily google can help you a lot.

But, to start... make your structure public, as someone else said!!!

Comment: Making it public doesn't help. THe Fusion Log Viewer looks promising, but how do you use it? The MSDN article isn't very helpful...

Comment: Ahh, found it. Had to add another path in my <probing> element. Weird still, as it was definately loaded in the current AppDomain - why would it need to search some paths still?

Answer (score 1):

Your struct is private. Deserialisation happens in the framework itself, not in your assembly. It's probably that's the problem, make it public and see if that solves it

Comment: Nop, that doesn't solve it at all. Besides - how could that affect anything, if the framework is unable to find the assembly as such?

Comment: Well I was vaguely hoping it might be a bad error message and that it found the assembly but couldn't access the class. Sometimes MS error messages suck :)